# How many times a number in list 1 appears in list 2 without using count()

Tags: list, frequency

trying to write this code to see how many times the numbers in list 1 appear in the list two, can use a nested for or while loop but I came up with this it doesn't work. I don't want to use count.

```
list1 = [4,7,2]
list2 = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
def compare(list1, list2):
    freq = ([i for i in list1 if i == num])
    return
print('The number 4 occurs in list2', freq, 'times')
print('The number 7 occurs in list2', freq, 'times')
print('The number 2 occurs in list2', freq, 'times')
```

Comment: Create a helper function that creates a dictionary containing the counts the number of occurrences of every number in a list. `For example given [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` it'll return the dictionary `{3: 1, 2: 2, 1: 3}`. Then, simply call this function on both lists to obtain their counts, and compare the dictionaries for equality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I understand the question,
but this code seems to work, though if it may be slow if you need it for an interactive program.
Hope this helps!

```
list1 = [4,7,2]
list2 = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
occurrences = [0,0,0]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in list2:
        if list1[i] == j:
            occurrences[i]+=1
print occurrences
```

Comment: `O(N^2)` hurts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list1 = [4,7,2]
list2 = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
occurrences = [0,0,0]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in list2:
        if list1[i] == j:
            occurrences[i]+=1
print occurrences
```